# Process Builder Apex CPU Limit Exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, administration, process-automation

I have Created a Process Builder and a check box on User level for Integration Users, during the execution of Process builder in First Node I am checking the Integration User check box if it is true then no action has to be done if it is false Process builder has to be executed. Even if that check box is true process builder is executing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This Apex CPU limit issues Comes during data loads I tried with user with integration user checkbox checked this process builder is not executing.

Any Ideas or Solutions would be great

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, process builder will always "execute" on the insert/update (depending on what you set) - I'd specify exactly what you mean by that as it seems you want it to execute your specific first action. However, your `DoNothing` action seems to be actually doing something. Is that what you intended? Created Date won't be null so it'll update your Annual Revenue.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I want Process Builder not to run for Integration User and Yes I changed Created Date Null Flag to True even then Process Builder going to Annual Revenue Node.

Comment: Is this on insert or update? Likewise, you wouldn't run into this issue if you actually "did nothing" instead of updating your Account's Annual Revenue. See [this](https://ericsplayground.wordpress.com/2016/11/10/how-to-tell-process-builder-to-do-nothing/) as as an example for apex/flow.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I changed DoNothing Action as you mentioned and Tried to load the data with User Intergration_User__c is checked this Process Builder is Firing and getting Apex CPU Limit

Comment: If you deactivate the process builder, do you still hit a CPU limit? I would assume you have other larger issues with your automation on account other than this one PB. I would suggest testing with different batch sizes as it's possible your automation was already "close" to hitting the limit so you need to look at your logic on account as a whole for batch improvements.